Using rosbag2_py to write static transform within a python script
I am currently writing a wrapper, that transform existing data into rosbag2 files using mcap. So far it works for Images, Lidar, IMU data. However, using Odometry looks good so far, although the referenced system header.frame_id and child_frame_id are not really showing up.
The most struggling part is with static transforms. I want to write the static tranfsroms into the bagfile, I already figured out the message I need for this, but it does not show in the transforms under tf2.
Here is my sample code:
import argparse
import csv
import cv2
import logging
import numpy as np
import os
import pandas as pd
import pickle
import sys
from scipy.spatial.transform import Rotation as R

import yaml

# ros specific
import rosbag2_py

from rclpy.time import Time
from rclpy.duration import Duration
from rclpy.serialization import serialize_message

from geometry_msgs.msg import TransformStamped
from std_msgs.msg import Header

storage_options = rosbag2_py._storage.StorageOptions(
      uri=args.output_bag_file,
      storage_id="mcap",
      max_bagfile_size="my_test_transfrom_bag")
converter_options = rosbag2_py._storage.ConverterOptions('', '')
  
writer.open(storage_options, converter_options)

qos_profile = "- history: 3\n  depth: 0\n  reliability: 1\n  durability: 1\n  deadline:\n    sec: 9223372036\n    nsec: 854775807\n  lifespan:\n    sec: 9223372036\n    nsec: 854775807\n  liveliness: 1\n  liveliness_lease_duration:\n    sec: 9223372036\n    nsec: 854775807\n  avoid_ros_namespace_conventions: false"

topic_info = rosbag2_py._storage.TopicMetadata(
        name="/tf_static",
        type='tf2_msgs/msg/TFMessage',
        serialization_format='cdr',
        offered_qos_profiles=qos_profile)
writer.create_topic(topic_info)

timestamp = Time(seconds=0, nanoseconds=0)

t = TransformStamped()
t.header.stamp = timestamp.to_msg()
t.header.frame_id = "odom"
t.child_frame_id = "vehicle"
t.transform.translation.x = 1.0
t.transform.translation.y = 2.0
t.transform.translation.z = 3.0
t.transform.rotation.x = 0.0
t.transform.rotation.y = 0.0
t.transform.rotation.z = 0.0
t.transform.rotation.w = 1.0

writer.write(
      "/tf_static",
      serialize_message(t),
      0)

This creates a mcap bagfile, but I can not access the transform, it does not show up.
Any ideas on that?
I checked by storing a bagfile with rosbag2 in the terminal and creating a static transform there, the difference in the mcap is that the transform is somehow stored withing MSG: rcl_interfaces/ParameterValue, which is missing when executing the python code above.

Does really no one has any idea on this topic?
